# Local Apache TLS Proxy error on Reverse Proxy for local services

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

I'm struggle now for a longer time with the following issue:

```
[gnutls:error] [pid 1878860] [remote 127.0.0.1:8282] ssl_engine_set: mod_proxy requested TLS proxy, but not enabled for piped.[CENSORED].de:443
```

I tried a lot to fix this but nothing helped. In this case I host Piped by myself and did a Let's Encrypt Certificate.

Here's the Apache Site Config of this service:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName piped.[CENSORED].de
        ServerAlias pipedapi.[CENSORED].de pipedproxy.[CENSORED].de
        ServerAdmin netzmeister@[CENSORED].de

        Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1

        SSLProxyEngine On
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8282/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8282/
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyAddHeaders On
        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"

        <LocationMatch "^/(/videoplayback|/api/v4/|/api/manifest/)">
            Header always set Cache-Control "private"
            Require all granted
        </LocationMatch>

        <Location "/">
            Header always set Cache-Control "public, max-age=604800"
            Require all granted
        </Location>

        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/pipedapi.[CENSORED].de/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/pipedapi.[CENSORED].de/privkey.pem
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I did already:

- Set `SSLProxyEngine` to `Off` and just used `ProxyAddHeaders On` and `RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"`.
- Placed `Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf` above `SSLProxyEngine`.
- Added an s behind http at `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` but got after an error:

```
[Sun Apr 09 19:15:35.915182 2023] [gnutls:error] [pid 1881378] [remote 127.0.0.1:8282] ssl_engine_set: mod_proxy requested TLS proxy, but not enabled for piped.[CENSORED].de:443
943 [Sun Apr 09 19:15:35.915210 2023] [core:error] [pid 1881378] [remote 127.0.0.1:8282] AH01961:  failed to enable ssl support [Hint: if using mod_ssl, see SSLProxyEngine]
944 [Sun Apr 09 19:15:35.915229 2023] [proxy:error] [pid 1881378] AH00961: https: failed to enable ssl support for 127.0.0.1:8282 (127.0.0.1)
```

The problem is only Caddy or nginx config snippets are on https://docs.piped.video/docs/self-hosting/ and didn't found any for apache. Piped will work almost fine (can't import lists) with this error but if it's possible I will kill this error to have a proper config/log.

Any ideas?

Comment: For starters, does your back-end actually support https on that port and can you actually make a HTTPS connection to httpS://127.0.0.1:8282/ with for example `curl` or `wget` ? Because that doesn't work then it won't work for Apache either.

Comment: @HBrujin: I get this with curl: `*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8282...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8282 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number`

Comment: As a comment  (rather than an edit into your question) that is a bit hard to read, but I *think* that looks like an error. That suggests the problem is in the back-end and you need to address that first.  (before you can see if you need to change Apache reverse proxy configuration to connect over https to your back-end) - **Note** that generally there is no security benefit to enable  TLS for connections to localhost  and off-loading HTTPS and let Apache connect with plain http to your  back-end does not compromise your security.

Comment: @HBruijn My goal is to eliminate the error message mentioned in my initial post. I also think that it isn't necessary to establish an internal TLS connection but the visitor have to. I got this error on every proxy reversed service on my server. But I have no clue to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found now the solution by a tip of person that I asked.

Just disable mod_gnutls by `a2dismod gnutls` and renew all Let's Encrypt Certificates. And it's gone!

It's really weak for such a huge user community that no one come up with that idea to do that. Why brings to pick a specific person from a search engine result the best solutions?!

But it's honorable that at least one person tried to help me!